# Simultaneously calling two different end points returns same data in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, api

I have a spring boot project with two endpoints `/historyReceived` and `/historySent`, both running the same query. When I call them separately they return correct data. But when I call them at the same time, `historySent` and `historyReceived` return the same response, but I should get different data. `historySent` data is correct, but `historyReceived` data is wrong and is the same as `historySent`.

Both endpoints have different controller methods that call a common service method.

Why this happening ? How to fix this ?

HistoryController.java

```java
     @AutoWired
    HistoryService historySerice;

    @AutoWired
    GenericService genericService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/historyReceived")
    public History historyReceived()
    {
        Long userid=genericService.getUserIdFromToken();
        return historySerice.getHistory(userid, "received");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/historySent")
    public History historySent()
    {
        Long userid=genericService.getUserIdFromToken();
        return historySerice.getHistory(userid, "sent");
    }
```

HistorySerice.java

```java
    public History getHistory(Long userid, String type)
    {
        return historyRepository.getHistoryData(userid, type);
    }
```

HistoryRepository.java

```
 @Query(value = "select * from History where user_id=:userid and type=:type", nativeQuery = true)
  History getHistoryData(@Param("userid") Long userid,
  @Param("type") String type);
```

Comment: How are calling at once - **But when I call them at the same time, historySent and historyReceived return the same response**

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar calling from two systems through postman. in one system received and in another system  historysent.

Comment: Please add the code for the `HistoryRepository` and `genericService.getUserIdFromToken`. At least one of these is keeping state leading to the wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the query i feel for type we should pass as @Param value "status", see the below modified query.

```
@Query(value = "select * from History where user_id=:userid and type=:status", nativeQuery = true)
  History getHistoryData(@Param("userid") Long userid,
  @Param("status") String type);
```

Comment: You can debug the SQL statements and check what the result it's returning. Add below props in applications.properties to debug

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

`logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @EnableCaching anywhere in your application? When you say *"But when I call them at the same time"* do you mean within the application? Can we see how you are doing this? As M. Deinum said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014559/simultaneously-calling-two-different-end-points-returns-same-data-in-spring-boot#comment111434908_63014559) please show the implementation of `genericService.getUserIdFromToken`

Comment: yes.  using the cache. (@EnableCaching ). but i did not use cache for the history methods. for decoding  the token and getting id i have cache. will that cause any problem ?

Comment: Are you using @Cacheable in the History repository? There is still some ambiguity around how you are calling these methods from outside of the server, and what you mean when you say you are calling them separately and then at the same time. Do you mean that in postman you try to make both calls at the same time?